# Handling redirections in angularJS using $location

Tags: angularjs

I have a url in the form of `url = localhost/abcd` . my present location is `localhost/ghi?p=1` How can I do a redirect to the using $location. `$location.path(url)` redirects me localhost/abcd?p=1. I want it to get redirected **localhost/abcd**

Answer (score 1):

You should use this like-

```
$location.path('/abcd');
```

I hope this will help you.